# Android add tm (trademark) symbol to text

Tags: java, android

How can I ad the TM symbol to a line of text like you would in HTML

```
&#0153;
```

Comment: Did you just post the answer to your own question in your question?  `&#0153;`

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you can't use the HTML entity you provided

```
&#0153;
```

you can use the unicode escape

```
String str = "\u2122";
```

or the character literal

```
String str = "™";
```

Answer (score 5):

For Android String.xml - use:

```
&#8482;
```

For example:

```
<string name="company_name">Company &#8482;</string>
```

This will show as:

Company ™

Answer (score 2):

To add any special character you just need to look up the Unicode character. Then you can append it to a string as below:

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();
char myUnicodeChar = '\u2122';
myString.append(myUnicodeChar);
```

Or as @Elliott suggested you can just use the literal:

```
StringBuilder myString = new StringBuilder();
char myUnicodeChar = '™';
myString.append(myUnicodeChar);
```

To look up a special character you can just say the name of the symbol + "unicode" in a Google search or use one of the following links to help find it:

- [Unicode Character Search](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm)
- [Unicode Lookup](http://unicodelookup.com/)